# C++/RapidJSON: Removing unicode Python prefix from JSON string for parsing

Tags: python, c++, json, unicode, rapidjson

I have a Python web API that returns a JSON with the "u" prefix instead of the standard double quotes.

I want to be able to parse this in C++ using the RapidJSON document.Parse(string) function, however the Python formatting prevents RapidJSON from validating it as a proper JSON.

What is the best way to properly format the JSON and remove the prefixes for parsing with RapidJSON?

The following is the string I want to parse using RapidJSON, however the IsObject() assertion fails (assuming RapidJSON cannot parse Python formatted unicode JSON strings).

```
{u'artist': u'Death Grips', u'track': u'Hunger Games', u'import_date': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 1, 4, 6, 23), u'track_id': u'TRUCCPM1515BB84DDF-0', u'codever': u'4.12', u'length': 159, u'score': 4.8918204, u'source': u'local', u'release': u'No Love Deep Web'}
```

Thanks!

Edit:

Turns out my response was not a JSON, but a Python dict. json.dumps on the dict was failing because of an unsupported type (datetime.datetime). I removed the offending entry using

```
del response.metadata[u'import_date'];
```

Then performing `json.dumps(response.metadata)`  worked properly and returned a JSON.

Comment: Are you sure it's JSON and not Python object notation?

Comment: This is a good point, I will look into encoding as JSON before returning the response in my Python API... I tried simply performing a json.dumps on the object but it breaks my server response completely.

Answer (score 0):

That is still not a valid JSON. You can use http://jsonlint.com/ or similar tool to validate a JSON. RapidJSON can only handle JSON conforming RFC7159/ECMA-404.